# PHP/CodeIgniter as middleware for mobile apps and website

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, mobile

I am planning to create a website and a web-service using Codeigniter (3.0.5). This web-service will serve data to the website.

But in the future I will create a mobile app using the existing web-service as data source.

This web-service will provide JSON response in every request from website/mobile apps.

My questions:

1. Since the website will access the web-service in curl/browser-less, session will not work. How I authenticate/keep-alive existing users which currently accessing the website/mobile apps?

**Imagined answer:** each time user authenticate, should the web-service creating some sort of session/user key with expiration time to the website and the key must be sent back from the website to the web-service for each request?

2. I want the web-service is only accessible from my website and mobile apps.

**Imagined answer:** create API/web-service key. The website/mobile apps must sent both the API key and session/user key I mentioned above. But from what I read, an API key are not supposed to stored in the mobile apps. How do I keep the api key secure?

Comment: Try doing some research on oAuth...it sounds like that is what you need here.

Comment: @mituw16 Thanks. Can I mention the website and mobile apps as Consumer, and the webservice as Service Provider? And which oauth should I choose? This page make me confused http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

Comment: One idea is to have your mobile app send login credentials with every single API request. Within CodeIgniter you can extend the CI_Controller to accommodate credential verification with every request from the mobile app.

Comment: Thank you guys...it seems I got a glimpse about how to use and implement oauth via this page: http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/

Now I just need to properly implement oauth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year after this question is posted!

I was stopped looking at oauth because I dont really understand the implementation. But after re-search, apparently **[JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://jwt.io/)** is the best solution for my situation.